# Corona SDK objects path

Tags: path, lua, coronasdk

I've been watching the Code of Martian Control Template here http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/martian-control and I want to try this: The ships land in the planets without drawing a path, I mean, each planet be the goal of certain ships but I want the ships move to the destination not only linearly, and that you have to touch them to destroy before land. But I dont know how to do that. Could you guys guide me about it please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Lua table for your randomly-drawn path. (I don't know what kind of path you want, if you be more specific, I can think about its production with random location functions etc.) Then, you use transition for every point in your location table.